# Repository and db specific business logic

Tags: repository, domain-driven-design

I need to place some complex business logic into db for perfomance reasons and I'm using respository pattern. The question is  -  should I invoke this business logic from the repository? I know that the repository shouldn't be aware of BL because it's just a mediator between the BL and data storage (it should contain only CRUD and query methods).
What do you think?

Comment: "place some complex business logic into db" => do you mean stored procedures ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The responsibility of a Repository is to provide a semblance of in-memory collection of entities to query from or add to. I don't know what kind of business logic you're talking about, but chances are it would break the single responsibility principle if you introduced it in a Repository. This would mean giving the Repository code many reasons to change, less cohesion and thus many reasons to break.

If you've got stored procedures with business logic in your database, I'd recommend you introduce some kind of interface between the calling code and the db to keep things decoupled. It wouldn't be a Repository since its purpose would be to trigger some business logic instead of persisting data, but the implementation could take the form of an Infrastructure Service for instance.

This will allow you to test your code in isolation using a mock db, and switch to another implementation of the db access interface to point to another DBMS, or even just to objects if you decide to give up on stored procedures at some point.